# AutoHotkeyA32 vs. AutoHotkeyU32 vs. AutoHotkeyU64

Tags: autohotkey

The portable `.zip` archive for [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) contains 3 executables: `AutoHotkeyA32.exe`, `AutoHotkeyU32.exe`, and `AutoHotkeyU64.exe`.

Based on the filenames, I assumed `32` and `64` refer to 32-bit and 64-bit respectively, while `A` and `U` refer to Admin and User permissions. However, if that is the case, it seems odd that `AutoHotkeyA32.exe` doesn't prompt for Admin rights when run, and that an `AutoHotkeyA64.exe` wouldn't also be included...

**What's the difference between the three AutoHotkey executables and which one should I be using?**

---

***Update***: The .exe properties reveal the `A` and `U` stand for [ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701882/3357935) and [Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241348/3357935) respectively. Still unsure what that means for regular program functionality.

[image: AutoHotkeyA32.exe Properties]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL:DR: Unless you are running legacy scripts, you should probably use AutoHotkeyU32.exe**

The "A" and "U" designations are for ANSI or Unicode support. [Citation](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/46563-unicode-version-of-autohotkey/)

If you are parsing files or manipulating data and need character support beyond the standard ASCII characters set, or need to send characters to a program in another language, then you need to use the unicode version.

If you know for certain that you will never see anything outside of the ANSI/ASCII alphabet then you want to use the "A" version.

The "A" version is probably also better on older operating systems where Unicode support is, to put it politely, less complete. While XP (I believe) did unicode, support has been greatly improved over time.

By default I've always used the unicode version on modern programs on modern systems without issue, if you see strange behaviours then you might need to call back to the ANSI version.

---

From [What to Autohotkey to choose?](http://maul-esel.github.io/ahkbook/en/What-Version-To-Choose.html)

> AutoHotkey_L is offered in an ANSI and an Unicode version. This describes a different script encoding (learn more…). You may not know a lot about it, but **Unicode often makes dealing with advanced topics (Windows API), but also hotkeys with special characters (ä, ö, ü, ß, Ø, Њ, ڵ, …) easier. On the other side, some old scripts from the forum might have minor issues**.

So if you have old scripts then they might need fixing, in which case the ANSI version might fare better, but the Unicode version will give you access to the Unicode versions of Windows API commands and makes dealing with special characters much easier.

---

Also, from [HowtoGeek: The Beginner’s Guide to Using an AutoHotkey Script](https://www.howtogeek.com/56481/the-beginners-guide-to-using-an-autohotkey-script/) the Autohotkey Installer

[image]

> We recommend to keep this at the default, Unicode 32-bit. If you’re running a 64-bit version of Windows you could opt for the 64-bit Unicode version, but it doesn’t offer significant performance gains for most scripts. **Regarding ANSI, you should  only choose this option if there’s a specific script you’d like to run which you know for sure doesn’t play well with Unicode.** This very rarely happens.

Comment: Today, 7 years after the HowToGeek article was published, the default selection on 64-bit systems is Unicode 64-bit. I'd say most users should stick with that unless they work in a mixed environment and need to compile.